# Django queryset how to get last n records?

Tags: django

I have an app where I want to display in template last 5 comments for every message. How can I get last n comments that matches a specific message? I've tried: `comments_all = Comments.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]` but it just returns 5 last comments regardless of message.

**models**

```
class Message(models.Model):
   host = models.ForeignKey(NewUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comments(models.Model):
   message = models.ForeignKey(Message, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   publisher = models.ForeignKey(NewUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   body = models.TextField(max_length=300)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**views**

```
def home(request):
   messages_all = Message.objects.all()
   comments_all = Comments.objects.all()

   form = AddComments()

   if request.method == "POST":
      form = AddComments(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         comment = form.save(commit=False)
         messageid = request.POST.get('message_id')
         comment.message_id = messageid
         comment.publisher = request.user
         comment.save()
      return redirect('home')


   last_five = Message.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
   context = {
      'messages_all':messages_all,
      'comments_all':comments_all,
      'form':form,
      'last_five':last_five
   }
   return render(request,'base/home.html', context)
```

Comment: `Comments.objects.filter(message=message).order_by('-created')[:5]`

Comment: but how do I define message?

Comment: @SzymonMudrak To answer this question you need to show your views

Comment: done, i've edited the post

Answer (score 1):

```
def home(request):
    messages_all = Message.objects.all()

    ...

    # construct a dictionary where each message.id is the key
    # and the value is the queryset for last 5 comments for the
    # matching message
    message_last_five = {
        msg.id: Comments.objects.filter(message=msg).order_by('-created')[:5]
        for msg in messages_all
    }

    # add message_last_five to your context
    context = {
      'messages_all': messages_all,
      'comments_all': comments_all,
      'message_last_five': message_last_five,
      'form': form,
      'last_five': last_five
   }
   return render(request,'base/home.html', context)
```

Although this perhaps can get you what you need - know that this is not an optimal solution because this is quite an expensive query to run.

And you can also achieve relatively the same thing with django templating instead too.